# How to combine these two PHP conditions into one statement

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am having an issue trying to figure out how best to combine the following to IF statements into one:

```
<?php if (!is_front_page() ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
```

But so far have come up short. I have tried all of the following to no avail:

```
<?php if (!is_front_page() ); AND if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>

<?php if (!is_front_page() ); AND (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>

<?php if (!is_front_page() ) AND if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>

<?php if (!is_front_page() ) AND (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
```

I am not fluent at all in PHP (obviously) and I wonder if someone could help me format this properly? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if(!is_front_page() && has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) { // your code }`

Answer (score 0):

You could write the two conditions within one statement.

Try this:

```
<?php if (!is_front_page() && has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ): ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD